# GNU Screen - create screen in background run command from shell or script

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I am trying to create a `screen` session/window from the shell and launch a command in it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 36):

If you want to launch and connect to screen:

```
screen CMD
```

If you want to launch and not connect to screen:

```
screen -dm CMD
```

Works with sessions too:

```
screen -Sdm NewDetachedSessionName CMD
```

You can send keypresses to `CMD` with `stuff`:

```
screen -S NewDetachedSessionName -X stuff "keypresses"
```

To send a new-line, include `\n` or `^M` or `$'\n'` with the *keypresses*.

Answer (score 2):

first create new session :

`screen -dmS [session_name]`

then attach command or script to run in session created :

`screen -x [session_name] [script.sh]`